# Perfectly centering content using css after pseudo selector

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Can anyone explain what is happening here?
Looking at the code below you would expect the two item to be aligned on top of each other.
This does not seem to be the case.

**HTML**

```
<div class="BX"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.BX{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
}
.BX:after{
  content:"×";
  position:absolute;
  font-size:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

**QUESTION**

I am aware I can easily hack at the code to alter the absolute offset however I am more interested in understanding where the after selector is deriving its top left position from?

http://jsfiddle.net/793vk/

Comment: set some border and find out http://jsfiddle.net/793vk/2/ that pseudo takes height/line-height from font-size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my two cents. At first, to diagnose the problem I set a `overflow:hidden` to the parent element `.BX` to study the problem. This is what I see. There is a clear overflow of the child element, and the `overflow:hidden` showcases that. But that still doesn't explain why the "pushing down" effect. Let's visualize how `font-size` and `line-height` are related.

[image] [image]

The child class inherits the parent class' `line-height` and it is imperative we must over write it. The `line-height` is actually by default calculated using the `font-size`. An overflow occurs which is visualized by pre-line height and post-line height stages, as shown in the images above. Remember, `line-height` for centering things isn't the best idea. Note how the pivot just moves a step up.

So what's happening here. We aren't moving the "X" up wards magically in the plane, but we are just pivoting upon the same point and just placing it's container class to move a step up. This is evident from the distance of the bottom of the "X" to the ending outline line.

[image] [image]

### Why does line-height:30px work?

The common practice is to use the golden ratio's value `1.618` to calculate the perfect line height, i.e. `line-height` = `font-size`/1.618. If you take the current `font-size` of 50px and calculate the `line-height` = 50/1.618 = 30. You do get ~30px.

### Reproducing the line-height explicitly

The reason the default `line-height` is that way is due to the formula `line-height` = `font-size`*1.2 which equals to `60px`, in our case. `(l = 50*1.2)`

If you try to reproduce the `line-height` by explicitly hitting the property in CSS, doing `line-height:60px`, you will reproduce the `line-height` as set in default by the browser.

[image]

Comment: Although several answer on here are correct this is by far the best presented answer I have ever seen for any question. If only every question was formatted so beautifully. Just excellent. Please take a moment to bask in my thanks and your achievement. :)

Comment: That being said "your line-height is broken" would also have been adequate. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks mate - I regularly try to create value in the community by answering the questions with as much knowledge as I can disseminate. I would add more to this answer, perhaps a small .gif animation to making it of lasting value.

Comment: If my answer is very well explained, your is very very well explained, +1!

Answer (score 3):

The top offset of the pseudo element is created because of the default `line-height` applied with `font-size:50px;` it makes the pseudo element 59px high and centers its content verticaly.

You may change this behaviour by setting a custom `line-height` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/793vk/5/)**

Comment: Yep, I went directly to solution instead of actually answering the question. Lesson learned.

Comment: well, i think to their credit, SO moderators are paying more attention to quality content. in this case (and to their credit) @obsidion was asking the why behind the problem rather than just a quick fix to a particular solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo element is bigger than it's parent, that is why it overflows.

Why is it bigger ? because of `font-size`, that gives it a `min-height` equal to `font-size` and a default `line-height` based on these `50px` you are given.

To see it in action add borders or background-color to pseudo : http://jsfiddle.net/793vk/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's positioned according to the positioned parent element as expected.

it is evident if you add a `border` around the `::after`

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/793vk/6/)

if you remove the fancy `font-size` , `font-weight` etc and you'll get expected result…

Check this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/793vk/3/)

Comment: I've up voted you, since you answered the question correctly in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
line-height: 25px;
```

to :after, 25px works pretty well. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/3JS3a/

Answer (score -1):

The :after pseudo element IS positioned at the top-left of the `.BX` element.

I've put a border on it to demonstrate that this is the case:

`border: 1px solid red;`

http://jsfiddle.net/793vk/4/

The reason it appears to be off-center is that the pseudo element is taller than `.BX`

Comment: Care to comment on the down vote? Obsidion's question was "I am more interested in understanding where the after selector is deriving its top left position from", and my answer explains that the top position is zero: exactly what Obsidion expected it to be.